# How to match exact string with space in solr

Tags: solr

This is my solr schema file code

```
   <field name="exactName" type="lowercase" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <copyField source="name" dest="exactName"/>
<fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and i index data : "**Amit Patel**" , "**india**"

now i want to search the data like :

> india

its searching fine , returned "india"

if i want to search

> amit patel

how to search this its giving exception and if i searched like that

> amit+patel

then also i am not getting "**amit patel**"   please suggest me how to implement case insensitive exact search (with space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've implemented it should be OK.

The rule is that if you want to only match the exact value of a field (but with optional filters applied), you can use the `KeywordTokenizer`. The Keyword Tokenizer keeps the whole input as a single token, before applying any filters.

Indexing "Amit Patel" will output one single token, "Amit Patel", which you can then apply a LowercaseFilter to, making the end result "amit patel", ending up with the definition you're already using:

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Remember to also sort in the correct field. If you're getting an exception, it's a good idea to start with the exception and work backwards from there. There is nothing in your syntax that should generate an exception from your example.

Comment: copyField already outside of field definition ... please check once again